# How to get contents of a span using .html()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get contents of a span using `.html()`. It is working for span that has no inner tags. but in other case all the tags are coming along. I only need the contents.

I added a snippet,

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#MainButton").click(function(){  
      var mainSpan = $("#MainSpan").html();
      alert(mainSpan);
  })
  
  $("#InnerButton1").click(function(){
      var innerSpan1 = $("#InnerSpan1").html();
      alert(innerSpan1);
  })
  
  $("#InnerButton2").click(function(){
      var innerSpan2 = $("#InnerSpan2").html();
      alert(innerSpan2);
  }) 
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="MainSpan" style="display:none">
  MainSpan
  
  <span id="InnerSpan1">
    InnerSpan1
  </span>

  <span id="InnerSpan2">
    InnerSpan2
  </span>

</span>

<button id="MainButton">Alert Main</button>
<button id="InnerButton1">Alert Inner 1</button>
<button id="InnerButton2">Alert Inner 2</button>
```

What I want is, on the click of button `Alert Main` I need the output something like

> MainSpan InnerSpan1 InnerSpan2

How do I get this?

Comment: Use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.text()` instead, if you want only the text:

```
var mainSpan = $("#MainSpan").text();
```

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#MainButton").click(function(){  
      var mainSpan = $("#MainSpan").text();
      alert(mainSpan);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="MainSpan" style="display:none">
  MainSpan
  
  <span id="InnerSpan1">
    InnerSpan1
  </span>

  <span id="InnerSpan2">
    InnerSpan2
  </span>

</span>

<button id="MainButton">Alert Main</button>
<button id="InnerButton1">Alert Inner 1</button>
<button id="InnerButton2">Alert Inner 2</button>
```

If you want it to be all on one line, you can use a regular expression to replace all whitespace with a single space:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $("#MainButton").click(function(){  
      var mainSpan = $("#MainSpan").text().replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').trim();
      console.log(mainSpan);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="MainSpan" style="display:none">
  MainSpan
  
  <span id="InnerSpan1">
    InnerSpan1
  </span>

  <span id="InnerSpan2">
    InnerSpan2
  </span>

</span>

<button id="MainButton">Alert Main</button>
<button id="InnerButton1">Alert Inner 1</button>
<button id="InnerButton2">Alert Inner 2</button>
```

Comment: `/\s+/g` should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, but `\s\s+` ensures that only *multiple* spaces get replaced by a single space, and that single spaces alone are not replaced with themselves again. A bit more efficient, but it doesn't really matter

Comment: @CertainPerfomance: True. But the first (single, only) whitespace could be a tab so should be replaced aswell